# Kafka Streams Intelligently skip messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple kafka 2.0.1 stream as explained in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/

Imagine the stream to be a series of stock prices. For each prices I trigger some CPU and I/O intensive computations. Obviously prices arrive at a very high rate so let's assume following scenario

1. Price arrives for a stock at 10AM and I schedule a series of computations which say take approx 3 minutes to finish.
2. In the meantime 3 prices arrive say at 10:01, 10:02 and 10:03

Is there any intelligent way in Kafka to skip the price update at 10:01, 10:02 and go straight to the one at 10:03 (i.e, the latest price update on the stock)? There is no point in me processing the updates at 10:01 and 10:02?

In akka I could perhaps do a custom mailbox. It is possible this isn't a pure streaming requirement however this sounded as a simple enough requirement that other people ought to have faced this.

Comment: There is no Kafka 2.12 -- 2.12 revers to the used Scala version that was used to compile the code.

Comment: Thanks, Indeed I now changed it to 2.0.1. However the question is generic in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KTable to store the updated state for stock prices. It will always keep the latest record and updates the previous value with the new one. If there are 3 records for key "**stock1**" and below records arrive in the stream at the given time

```
<stock1, 10> // at time 10:01
<stock1, 8>  // at time 10:02
<stock1, 13> // at time 10:03
```

KTable will result in  `<stock1, 13>` for stock1.

Kafka will produce the eventual results based on the event time.  I would recommend to go with KTable and always pick the latest record from the stream.

You can find more information about KTables : https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#ktable